# Leave Month (Date) Field blank (Optional)

Tags: nodes, entities

I was wondering if it's possible to have Drupal (7), leave the Month field NULL (empty).

When someone sets a Date, sometimes they don't need to enter a Month along with it. When I try this by Default, Drupal says a Month is needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Number field and do the validation if you just want to store only DD(Day).

[Date picker](https://www.drupal.org/project/datepicker) is using to collect Day Month Year